# ¿Cómo tener variantes del código en un mismo repositorio?

Tags: php, git

Tengo un proyecto de php en el cual tengo mi propio framework, y tengo alrededor de 20 clientes que usan el framework (la misma base), pero diferente lógica en controladores y modelos ejemplo, todo el core se repite en todos los clientes pero los controladores y modelos no, en el momento tengo un repositorio por cada cliente pero se dificulta mucho sostener el framework ya que si cambio algo en el core me toca ir cliente por cliente a bajar cambios, ¿hay alguna forma de realizar esto en un solo repositorio?, ¿Qué temas debo de investigar?

Comment: investiga DDD, principios SOLID, patrones de diseño, y en general te recompendaria que leyeras "Codigo limpio" de Robert C. Martin. Por otra parte, recuerda que S.O. es para responder a problemas concretos, asi que es posible que te cierren la pregunta, pues esto no es de programacion, sino mas bien "formacion"

Comment: @Jakala Gracias por tu comentario amigo, una pena que eliminaran la pregunta fue de mucha utilidad tu comentario.

Comment: Con una rama por cliente?

Comment: @Cuauhtli Si puede ser una opción pero no interfiere el funcionamiento para cuando cree ramas por desarrollo, o tendría que tener una nomenclatura ?

Comment: Investiga [`submódulos`](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos)

Comment: Pues si todas tienen el mismo core, entonces todas tienen un mismo commit base en común (le puedes llamar a "master" mejor "core"). Cada rama tiene cosas que otras no. Deberían de ser CASI mutuamente excluyentes salvo el "core". Si vas a hacer cambios en el core, entonces deberías hacer un pull o rebase en las ramas de los clientes, aka, hacerlo tu en tu repo local + darle push + decirle a tus clientes que hagan pull o rebase o reset de sus ramas las tuyas actualizadas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo le dí en cerrar a la pregunta (y sostengo mi voto porque es vaga la pregunta) pero es interesante y no tan poco frecuente.

Una propuesta es que en lugar de llamar a la rama principal y estable "master" o "main", se llame "core". Tan sólo para indicar que no es la rama principal, sino la base de las demás ramas de larga duración.

Se me hizo interesante porque mientras el patrón usual del desarrollo de software es tener ramas de corta duración (git flow, trunk based, feature based, etc), este problema plantea no una rama "principal", sino un core o base para otras que NO SERÁN DE CORTA DURACIÓN sino PERMANENTES o muy larga duración.

Además de llamar a la rama "core", se me ocurré que crees ramas para cada cliente aunque tengan unas cuantas redundancias entre estas (mejor tener pocas sanas redundancias que mil ramificaciones que "parecían buenas para simplificar una feature entre dos de los mil clientes").

En cualquier cambio al core, tú mismo hacer el push a las ramas remotas desde tu repositorio local, así abordas localmente posibles discrepancias. Una vez resueltas las posibles discrepancias y CORRIDOS TUS MALDITOS UNIT TESTS e INTEGRATION TESTS, y el FUNCIONAMIENTO de las nuevas VALIDADO POR TUS CLIENTES EN MALDITOS ENTORNOS DE PRUEBA, con Data Quality checks, donde todo será firmado APROBADO POR ESCRITO!, solo LUEGO DE ESO darle push o a "core" o a cada branch según el caso. Luego del push, decirles que tipo de estrategia tienen que seguir. Quizás un simple pull, o fetch + reset, o commit + pull + push. Y si es al "core", avisarle a toooodos tus clientes que hagan tal o cual procedimiento de update o testing (Que relajo!)

Ahí reside en por qué voté en cerrar tú pregunta, porque es tremendamente amplia.

La otra opción es que el core de framework lo podrías guardar en un artefacto constantemente actualizado, por ejemplo, un jar o python zip, o como lo tengas, y almacenarlo en un artifactory como Nexus o jFrog, y una vez que actualizas ese core, decirle a los clientes que corran su script de CI/CD para hcer un rebuild y redeploy con los últimos cambios de tu core. O tú los puedes hacer por ellos convenciendolos de que te den el control de sus repositorios.

Como vez, la pregunta es tremendamente amplia sin soluciones 100% reproducibles, testeables.

Para que la segunda opción sea viable y que en caso de errores puedas hacer roll back, es necesario que cada artefacto que subas tenga un nombre como SNAPSHOT-1.2.jar, o RELEASE-1.2.3.zip, o RELEASE-{hash del commit}.jar, etc. Así cualquier pedo, les puedes decir que solo actualicen sus jobs parametrizados de CI/CD y den rollback o lo que consideres más adecuado según tu caso.

En este caso de roll back, en la estrategia de git tan solo sería un `git revert` y coordinar de nuevo todos los redeployments con tus clientes.

Supongo que lo podrías automatizar en todos los servidores o clusters que contengan el framework de tus clientes con scripts de terraform o Bash <3, pero enorme scope de la pregunta sigue siendo un problema.

Y como preguntaste qué cosas estudiar, te recomiendo: CI/CD (git, algun servicio o servidor de CI/CD como jenkins o spinnaker o gitlab ci/cd o github actions), Data Quality Assurance, artifactories, versionado de software, Systems Development Life Cycle